# Find directory of a file in Python

Tags: python

If I have the following file:

```
file = '/Users/david542/Desktop/work.txt'
```

I can use `os.path.basename(file)` to get the file name.

What command would I use to get the directory of the file (i.e., to get "/Users/david542/Desktop") ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.path.dirname(file)` returns the directory of the passed file name. Alternatively, you can use `os.path.split(file)` which will give you a tuple containing the directory name and the file name in one call.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('/Users/david542/Desktop/work.txt'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.dirname(file)` will yield directory name.
`import os

print(os.path.dirname("c:/windows/try.txt"))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for `os.path.dirname`. Otherwise you could use `os.path.split` which returns the path and the filename in a tuple.